# Maven clover2 triggers duplicate class exception

Tags: java, maven, clover

This is in reference to the JIRA ticket at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CLOV-1471

The problem is similar to what was posted on the JIRA dashboard, i.e. :
We have several maven projects that have more than one source directory. The non-default directories are added using the build-helper plugin. The clover2:setup goal instruments all source folders, but then sets all non-generated directories as source folders on the maven project. That results in compile errors, since source files are both present in the clover instrumented sources and original location.

Here's how we are using the build-helper-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.9.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>add-shared-source</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>add-source</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<sources>
<source>../SomeOtherModule1/src/main/java/com</source>
<source>../SomeOtherModule2/src/main/java/com</source>
<source>../SomeOtherModule3/src/main/java/com</source>
</sources>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

and this is how we are using the clover2 plugin in a build profile:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
<configuration combine.self="override">
<targetPercentage>$
{code_coverage_target}
</targetPercentage>
<licenseLocation>$
{clover_license_location}
</licenseLocation>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>verify</phase>
<goals>
<goal>instrument-test</goal>
<goal>check</goal>
<goal>clover</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

without the clover plugin, the build compiles fine. but after adding the clover plugin, we get several errors saying duplicate classes found.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is caused by a fact that you're using the clover2:instrument instead of the clover2:setup goal. The clover2:instrument forks a custom build life cycle and in this build cycle it performs instrumentation in the 'validate' phase. Due to a fact that your 'add-source' goal is bound to the generate-sources phase, the build-helper-maven-plugin runs after Clover instead of before.

I suggest to use clover2:setup bounded to the validate or initialize phase (i.e. before the generate-sources one).